# NullPoint exception on value returned from asyncTask

Tags: java, android, bitmap, android-asynctask

i don't understand why the bitmap is null. I' ve tested the value returned from `doInbackGround()` and it is not null, as well as is not null `onPostExecute()` method. ***The AsyncTask is executed before using the bitMap but this value is null anyway.***

my AsyncTask:

```
public class ImageTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Bitmap> {

    private Display display;

    public ImageTask(Display display) {
        this.display = display;
    }

    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(Void... params) {
        Bitmap overlay;
        try {
            URL url = new URL(...);
            HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            connection.connect();
            InputStream input = connection.getInputStream();
            overlay = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(input);
            connection.disconnect();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            return null;
        }
        return overlay;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (bitmap != null)
            display.setBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

i start the AsyncTask here in class Display:

```
public class Display{
     private Bitmap bitmap;
     ...

public void setBitmap(Bitmap bitmap) {
        this.bitmap = bitmap;

    }

public void func(){ 
          ....
          new ImageTask(this).execute();
          canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 25, 25, null); -> bitmap  is null here !?!?!
          ....   
}
```

my logcat:

```
08-25 10:19:00.757: E/AndroidRuntime(4322):     FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-25 10:19:00.757: E/AndroidRuntime(4322):     java.lang.NullPointerException
08-25 10:19:00.757: E/AndroidRuntime(4322):     at android.graphics.Canvas.throwIfRecycled(Canvas.java:1025)
08-25 10:19:00.757: E/AndroidRuntime(4322):     at android.graphics.Canvas.drawBitmap(Canvas.java:1065)
08-25 10:19:00.757: E/AndroidRuntime(4322):     at com.graphic.core.Display.addMarker(Display.java:51)
```

*Now i have a dubt, when i do  `asyncTask.execute()` the rows below this instruction are executed? or these rows are executed only after the asyncTask is finished?* *I think the rows are executed after `onPostExecute()`, but i would a clarification on that.*

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`asyncTask.execute()` starts an asynchronous operation. This means the code in the `AsyncTask` will run parallel to your synchronous code. So all the code after `asyncTask.execute()` will be run before or in parallel to the code in your `AsyncTask`. So this code:

```
new ImageTask(this).execute();
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 25, 25, null);
```

will not work. The first line starts the `AsyncTask` and immediately after that you attempt to draw the `Bitmap`. What you have to do is return the `Bitmap` in `onPostExecute()`. Of course you are already doing that with the `setBitmap()` method, but what is missing is that only **after** calling `setBitmap()` you should attempt to draw it.

Comment: ok, i understood. I have a question to make if i have this situation: `new Foo(this, new Task(value).execute().get());` and no rows below this line. In this case the `value` passed on Foo will be null? or before creating the object it will wait for asyncTask to finish.

Comment: By calling `get()` you are forcing the UI thread to wait for the `AsyncTask` to finish. This is exactly what you **DO NOT** want. You are using an `AsyncTask` to offload work into a separate thread so your UI will always remain fluid and responsive. If you call `get()` you are forcing the code in the `AsyncTask` to essentially run synchronously again eliminating any advantage the `AsyncTask` might have to offer! It would be the same as using no `AsyncTask` at all.

Comment: ok i' ll keep in mind, thanks a lot for the good explanations.

Answer (score 0):

An AsyncTask is running in parallell with the UI thread, thus `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 25, 25, null);` is called while the image is being downloaded. Since the image is not set yet, you get a `NullPointerException`.

Try putting `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 25, 25, null);` in `setBitmap(Bitmap);` instead of in `func();`

Answer (score 0):

Move this `canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 25, 25, null);` inside `onPostExecute()`.

AsyncTask runs in different thread. So these lines will be executed without waiting for the results from AsyncTask.

Answer (score 0):

`canvas.drawBitmap` and your AsyncTask are running in parallel. So drawing happens even before AsyncTask is finished. Move your `canvas.drawBitmap` to `setBitmap()`

Answer (score 0):

it's normal that the bitmap is null when you call

```
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap, 25, 25, null)
```

because **you didn't wait for the async task to return the result**. you should call drawBitmap in **onPostExecute** and probably call **invalidate()** on the view to force it redraw